# CAPTCHA not registering as on/Image not appearing

Tags: ee1, captcha

I have three sites that I'm adding CAPTCHAs to (www.hoekstratruck.com/index.php/contact, www.hoekstratransportation.com/index.php/contact, and www.hoekstraspecialty.com/index.php/contact/ctest).  On the first two, the captcha works fine.  It shows up and says that it is required to submit the form.  On the third site, however, when I include the {if captcha} tag, nothing shows up.  If I leave that tag out, just having

`<p>Please enter the word you see in the image below:<br/>
    {captcha}<br /> <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" /></p>`

it displays the prompt and the text box, but not the image (and it doesn't print "{captcha}" either).  I have double checked that the server path and image html path are both correct.

All three sites are running off EE v1.7.1 and I don't see any difference in how the first two sites are set up compared to the third site.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This has bitten me a few times and it has always been a path issue. [Double check your captcha preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/captcha_preferences.html).

Also, make sure the captcha directory/folder is writable by your webserver

Comment: I have double (and triple) checked the paths, and they seem to be correct.  When I enter the full URL to the CAPTCHA folder and add the name of one of the images, for example http://www.hoekstraspecialty.com/images/captchas/1371664869.85.jpg, I can see it in the browser.  The folder itself has file permission 777, while the images are set to 644.  This is the same as on the other two sites I listed in my initial post.

Comment: I now have the captcha on one [form](http://www.hoekstraspecialty.com/index.php/shop/rentals/) working while the [other](http://www.hoekstraspecialty.com/index.php/contact/ctest) doesn't work.  The only difference is that the second one is in a table while the first isn't.  Any ideas?

Comment: Both captchas are now working, though one of them is not in the '{if captcha}  {/if}' tags.  No idea what made them suddenly appear.

Comment: I wish I could help more but I am trying to remember what else would cause them to not show up... especially if you are using the same code with correct settings across all the site.